# Is it a medical condition to not able to recall the word in a language while having a conversation

Tags: neuroscience, medicine, memory, neurophysiology, cognition

While having a conversation it happens to some peopl that clearly they know there exists a perfect word to be used but can not recall it during the conversation in real time and hence forced to use some other word which may not be so perfect.

But after the conversation is done they will be able to recall it. This happens very frequently to some people. Is this some kind of medical condition. If yes what is the name of this condition called as. ?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! Thanks for your question. Self-help questions are strongly discouraged, so as to stimulate folks to seek professional help where necessary. Please remove any self-reference, otherwise the question may be closed. Secondly, it may be wise to post this question on Cognitive Sciences.SE as it may attract more attention there.

Comment: @ChrisStronks Thanks. Removed the self references

Comment: Have you read anything about any kinds of memory loss? Most accurately: maybe it is an illness, maybe it isn't.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Or may be it is a resultant of cannabis :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon you describe is known as [tip-of-the-tongue phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_of_the_tongue), where you know there is a word, and you feel it's "right on the tip of the tongue, but doesn't come out".

The phenomenon is normal and tends to worsen with age. Only in case it becomes so strong that it seriously interferes with daily life, it can be considered a medical condition (anomic aphasia) that may be indicative of damage to the brain, such as stroke, head trauma, dementia, or tumor.